# Struggles with acceleration in polar coordinates

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, kinematics, rotational-kinematics

> "The velocity of a point moving in a plane is the resultant of a velocity $v$ along the radius vector and a velocity $v$' parallel to a fixed line. Show the accelerations are:
>
> > $\frac{dv}{dt}+\frac{vv'}{r}cos\theta$ , $\frac{dv'}{dt}+\frac{vv'}{r}$

> where $\theta$ is the angle between the radius vector and the fixed line.

My working so far has been:
$v_r=v+v'cos(\theta)$ , $v_\theta =v'sin(\theta )$,  $\omega= \frac{v'sin(\theta )}{r}$
$a_r=(\frac{dv}{dt}-\frac{dv'}{dt}cos(\theta )+v'\omega sin(\theta ))\hat{r} + (v\omega-v'\omega cos(\theta ))\hat{\theta }$ , $a_\theta=(\frac{dv'}{dt}sin(\theta )+v'\omega cos(\theta ))\hat{\theta }-(v'\omega sin(\theta ))\hat{r}$
$a_r=(\frac{dv}{dt}-\frac{dv'}{dt}cos(\theta )+v'\omega sin(\theta )-v'\omega sin(\theta ))\hat{r} =\frac{dv}{dt}-\frac{dv'}{dt}cos(\theta )$
$a_\theta=(\frac{dv'}{dt}sin(\theta )+v'\omega cos(\theta )+ \omega v-v'\omega cos(\theta ))\hat{\theta }=(\frac{dv'}{dt}sin(\theta )+ \omega v)\hat{\theta }=\frac{vv'sin(\theta )}{r}$
$a_l=\frac{a_\theta }{sin(\theta)}=\frac{dv'}{dt}+\frac{vv'}{r}$

Which is correct for $a_l$ but not for $a_r$, unless $\frac{vv'}{r}=-\frac{dv'}{dt}$.
Is this relation true and if so how is it derived? Or do I have a conceptual error about the accelerations?